# How can I achieve the same functionality of Google Chrome's "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in JavaScript or html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a site that displays text from a JSON file. It also lets the user add text, delete text, and update existing text. I have it set up so that when a user presses a button (add btn, delete btn, update btn), the changes are written to the JSON file and the page is refreshed. When the page refreshes it reads the JSON file (which I have confirmed, is the new version), but it does not display the new data.

I have checked, in depth, that the JSON file is modified before the page is reloaded.

```
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
   let myJson = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
   /*do something*/
 }
```

At this point: although the JSON file has been modified, the old one is still being read. The new JSON file is read when I do the empty cache and hard reload.

I have already tried in JavaScript:

```
location.reload(true)
```

And in HTML, combinations of the following:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

None of this has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope u did't save the value in db. just hold all update value in **myJson**

To solve your problem, Just Save the data into local storage instead of variable

```
localStorage.setItem("myJson",JSON.parse(request.responseText));
```

if every add,update delete
modify the local storage  so that local storage have new updated data

on page load check local storage  have value if have value don't send request to server 
just read it from local storage 
like bellow

```
var myJson= localStorage.getItem("myJson",JSON.parse(request.responseText));
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's possible, you can add a query string on the end of whatever file or request you are making.

if you need to request the URL like `$.get('myapi/getfile');`, try adding the current date/time at then end like this:

```js
$.get('myapi/getfile?cachebreaker=' + Date.now());
```

which would produce a URL like `myapi/getfile?cachebreaker=1553709710447` which browsers will interpret as a new request and not use cache

Comment: I tried several ways of doing this, and maybe I'm just missing something, but to do this, the file I am getting must also have the same query string at the end and I tried  doing that (using require('fs') ) in JavaScript but it did not work in chrome.

Comment: I don't know how everything you're using works or what your knowledge-level on this stuff is. but it's possible to add multiple query strings on a URL with `&` like this`myapi/getfile?someParam=true&id=4&cachebreaker=1234`